# How does Sails.js manages data without saving in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I am very new to `MVC` and `Sails.js`. I just started learning it yesterday and tried to learn it by doing something. But I am having some confusions regarding Sails models.

After creating the application, I configured the database in `config/connection.js`. Then I created a `blueprint api` named `user`. Next thing I did is I started the server and loaded following url:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create?user=Mr.X
```

I didn't configure anything in `api/models/user.js`. So it is not supposed to save any data in database. When I browse my database as expectedly I can't see any record. But when I load the following url:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/
```

I can see the record of `Mr.X` there. And even if I restart the server the record of `Mr.X` is still there. What I can't understand is, how is it happening? How is Sails saving this data without affecting the configured database? Is it normal thing in all `MVC` frameworks or just Sails do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you set up a connection in **config/connections.js**, but didn't specify a *default* connection in **config/models.js**, so your app is still using the default `localDiskDb` connection.  You can see this database by opening the **.tmp/localDiskDb.db** file in your project.  It's a pretty handy development tool.

See the [docs for **config/models.js**](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.models.html) for more info on global model settings.  You can also set a connection on a per-model by basis using the `connection` property in the model's class file (e.g. **api/models/User.js**).

Answer (score 0):

All your user data gets stored in localDiskDb.db by default.
You can Use postman app for retrieval and insertion of records.
Its better for you to first go through these videos.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60PaCpTP5L4&list=PLLxyAuVpwujMQjlsF9l_qojC31m83NOCG&index=2